# Custom javascript extension wont execute my script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, console.log

I have this code I want to execute everytime I watch a youtube video:

```
alert("Test alert");

var title = $(".style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer").textContent.toUpperCase();
var blackword = "fortnite".toUpperCase();
if (title.includes(blackword)) {
    alert("Video contains fortnite!");
    window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com";
}
```

When I visit www.youtube.com I get the test alert and nothing else happens which is fine because the script should execute only when the youtube title contains the word 'fortnite'.

I have two problems;
when I click on the video, even the test alert doesn't execute. But if I refresh the video window (with the URL something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYZ), test alert shows up, but other script doesn't execute. (When I input it manually in the console, it works..)
Does anybody seem to know what is the problem?
I am using chrome extension Custom Javascript.

Comment: Youtube doesn't do a full page refresh on video link click. You'll have to add some sort of  event listener to catch those clicks.

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)